# C++ escrever em arquivos

Tags: c++

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream f_out;
    f_out.open("teste.txt");

    if(! f_out.good())
        return -1;
    else cout << "Arquivo criado!";

    string str = "String";
    f_out << str;

    f_out.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Esse código deveria escrever em um arquivo `txt`, mas não o faz. O que devo fazer para que seja escrito qualquer coisa em um arquivo `txt` usando a função `open` para abrir o arquivo?

Comment: Experimente colocar o caminho completo do arquivo. Poderia fornecer mais detalhes? Qual compilador estás usando? Qual sistema operacional?

Comment: Não. Apenas o arquivo não é criado, pelo que revisei o código está correto.

Comment: Mac OS,@Avelino.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode estar usando  **ofstream** que é uma classe para fluxo de saida que opera em arquivos.

**EDIT**: Lembre de estar passando o modo de abertura e o diretório completo do arquivo que deseja manipular caso ele não esteja na mesma pasta do executável de seu programa.

**Exemplo**: `f_out.open("C:\\Users\\Pasta\\teste.txt", std::ios::app);`

Veja também a referência  [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/)

```
std::ofstream Hypnos_FILE;
std::string TEXTO = "Escrevendo em arquivo de texto";
Hypnos_FILE.open("DATABASE\\Arquivo.txt", std::ios::app);
if (Hypnos_FILE.is_open())
{
   std::cout << "Arquivo de texto aberto com sucesso!" << std::endl;

   Hypnos_FILE << TEXTO;

}
else
   std::cout << "Erro ao abrir arquivo de texto.";

Hypnos_FILE.close();
```

**open (filename, mode);**

**ios::in**  =  Aberto para operações de entrada.

**ios::out** =  Aberto para operações de saída.

**ios::binary** = Abrir em modo binário.

**ios::ate** = Definir a posição inicial no final do ficheiro.
Se este sinalizador não estiver definido, a posição inicial é o início do arquivo.

**ios::app** = Todas as operações de saídas são realizadas no final do ficheiro, adicionando o conteúdo para o atual conteúdo do ficheiro.

**ios::trunc** = Se o arquivo é aberto para operações de saída e ele já existia, o seu conteúdo anterior é eliminado e substituído por um novo.

Comment: Acha que devo adicionar o caminho ao usar a função open, @Rhayden?

Comment: Se você deixar como esta : f_out.open("teste.txt");
ele só vai abrir o arquivo se estiver no mesmo diretório do executável do seu programa

Comment: você também não informou o modo de abertura

Comment: experimente algo como
f_out.open("teste.txt", std::ios::app);

Comment: O modo de abertura padrão é out, quando não informado.

Comment: A função deve criar um doc com mesmo nome no diretório. Mas por via das duvidas coloquei um doc na pasta do projeto.

Comment: Ahh, você tem que passa como escrita então..

Comment: Passar como escrita? já não esta?

Comment: Sim..

std::ofstream guides_txt;

guides_txt.open("GUIDES\\BROWSERS_PASSWORDS_LOCATION.txt");

Comment: Já usei: ofstream f_out e so depois usei a função open. :/

Comment: tenta usar o is_open() ao inves do if(! f_out.good())

Comment: Era simplesmente o caminho. Agora deu certo. Muito obrigado pela atenção. A educação evolui graças a pessoas como você.

Comment: o/ boa rapaz!! quando precisar estamos ai! :)